# Force USB tethering on an Android

Tags: command-line, usb-tethering

I am using a Windows system and I want to add my old tablet (Acer Iconia A1-810 without LTE) as a second monitor. It is running Android 4.4.2 Kitkat, and I found an app for Android called spacedesk to do that. Wi-Fi connection is very slow, and I want to use USB Tethering to connect the tablet as a monitor, but there is no option in the tablet settings. So I rooted the tablet to use command lines to start it somehow, but I can't figure out a way. **Is there a way to use command lines or some way to force start USB tethering on Android?**

So far I tried rooted and unrooted apps to start USB tethering but nothing happens. I'm not sure if the tablet  supports it and if it doesn't is there a way to embed it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: See if any of the solutions work: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127930/96277